# SharePoint calendar, users self register

Tags: 2010, calendar, register

I have a SharePoint Calendar where I publish events.

At the moment, users need to click a link on the item with a predefined "mailto:..." and send the email, but I would like to create some kind of button that will create a new item in a separate sharepoint list.

Can this be done without development or SharePoint designer? Is there any possibility of creating a link with a function that will create a new item with the user name and the event the user is registering to? I am using SP 2010.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will need to be 'custom', but the level of customization can vary. Easiest: Setup your signup list with a lookup to the calendar list. Add a button on the event page that sends the user to the NewForm of the sign up list, with the event ID in the query string, and then a small script there that auto-selects the calendar event from a lookup.

From there, your level of complexity will climb with options around custom web parts, list definitions, etc.